# Django Registration Redux

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I want to implement the registration and login function using the Django registration Redux package. I follow step by step the Quick start guide:

https://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

Run: python manage.py runserver

And I put in the browser:

```
Http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register/
```

And I get the page completely blank

My project is in:

```
Https://github.com/barkalez/catataxov2
```

Comment: Did you add `registration` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting? https://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#settings

Comment: You are going to have to provide some more information, if you want help track down the error. For example what URL are you pointing your browser at and what webpage is being displayed?

Comment: Also show us your `urls.py`

Answer (score 0):

In your settings, you didn't add the path to your own templates, something like:
as you use

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

it should be something like:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'registration/templates')],
```

and furthermore, you didn't set the standard url for django-registration-redux:

```
path('accounts', include('registration.backends.default.urls'))
```

However, you use twice registration: once for your app, once for the folder. It is rather confusing. Renaming the app would make your project more readable.